# Set invalid a input manually in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a form created with formbuilder:

```
constructor(){
    this.userForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'firstname': ['', Validators.required],
        'lastname': ['', Validators.required],
        'email': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, ValidationService.emailValidator])]
    });
}
```

I want set invalid the firstname field. How I can do it?

**EDIT:**

I want set invalid the firstname field manually, like so:

`this.userForm.firstname.valid = false`

Comment: it is Invalid if it is empty

Comment: The default state of the field is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

It is invalid if it is empty or if you don't need the validation on the `firstname` you don't need to put it in the validation of the `formBuilder`